# Add YouTube Data API to Android Studio

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, gradle, android-studio

So, I am currently messing around with android programming in my free time, and I am using android studio as my ide of choice.  I am currently trying to make a very simple app using the youtube api.  My issue is that I cant figure out how to actually get the api into my application.  I have used file>project structure to add the stuff to my application, but that doesnt work by itself.  It stops yelling at me about syntax errors but when it compiles it errors.

I researched this a bit and have found that I need to add stuff to build.gradle or settings.gradle(or both) but i havent found a definitive answer on exactly what to do.  Everything I have tried thus far hasnt worked.  SO if someone could either explain to me what i have to do, or link me to a place where it explains what to do that would be great

--edit--

I am so confused right now.  I started a new project.  I added the libs and it was still able to compile.  I then added the imports and it threw errors about it.  I then added these to the build.gradle and it was able to compile perfectly

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs/youtube', include: '*.jar')
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs/youtube/libs', include: '*.jar')
```

But when i added this code that requires the library

```
/** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();

/** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

/** Global instance of Youtube object to make all API requests. */
private static YouTube youtube;
```

the syntax was fine but it threw an error upon compiling it

```
 Gradle: Execution failed for task ':Apitest:dexDebug'.
> Failed to run command:
```

and that was followed by about 100 lines of of file locations

Any ideas as to what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 43):

Just add this dependency in gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev181-1.22.0'
```

and use YouTube object.

reference:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/youtube/v3

Comment: Well, I thought this worked, but it actually caused it to break. That was my own doing though. I just need the player. not the data api

Answer (score 17):

Step 1: Download YoutubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar from https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/

Step 2: Paste it in libs folder inside app folder of project

Step 3: Add following line to build.gradle in app folder of project:

```
compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
```

Step 4:Add following imports to activity which extends `YouTubeBaseActivity` and implements `YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener`

```
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;
```

Step 5: Inside `OnCreate` method:

```
//Make sure you initialize youtube player

YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);

youTubeView.initialize(YoutubeAPIKey, this);
```

Where `YouTubeAPIKey` you would get from google console after you register your project in web mode, dont select mobile domain like Android or any

Step 6: Override methods in interface implemented as:

```
@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0,
        YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "Oh no!      
    "+error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer player,
        boolean arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    player.loadVideo(VIDEO_ID);
}
```

Where VIDEO_ID is fetched from RESTful call to Youtube API at:
"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search" with suitable parameters passed in GET like, "q,relevanceLanguage,type,key" etc.

Comment: Adding `compile files('libs/...jar')` is not necessary. The fileTree is already complied by default

Comment: good answer, but one more thing.
should be added in settins.gradle:
include ':app', ':YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi'