# Unable to get a YouTube video to play with Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-youtube-api

I know that if you want to play a YouTube video, your activity has to extend `YouTubeBaseActivity` and implement `YouTubePlayer.OnInitialzedListener`, but what if those aren't being recognized in **Android Studio**?

I've gotten it to work with *Eclipse* multiple times, but this is my first app in Android Studio and I'm not finding a lot of resources to help me know what to do differently.

```
public class VideoPlayerActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener{
```

This is the code in `onCreate` I used in Eclipse:

```
ytpv = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayer);
ytpv.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
```

Also this:

```
@Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Initialization Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

And the clincher where `filename` was just the youtube id:

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasrestored) {
    yt_player = player;

    Bundle info = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(info == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "No extras!");
        return;
    }

    fileName = info.getString("filename");

    if(fileName.equalsIgnoreCase("null")){
        availability.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ytpv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else{
        Log.d(TAG, "Play video!");
        yt_player.loadVideo(fileName);
    }
}
```

Layout file looks like this:

```
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/youtubeplayer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/eturl"
    >
</com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView>
```

Any tips/advice/critique will be warmly welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on [this Google product forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/FQoBYsObhBQ)  which helped to solve my problem of the video not playing (see my comment on my answer). :)

SOLUTION: Give ONLY the **YouTube ID** and not the entire YouTube URL to the `loadVideo()` function.

Answer (score 3):

This helped me: [Add YouTube Data API to Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18175397/956975)

1 - I actually forgot to get the library .jar file from the Eclipse project where I got it to work (noob fault).

2 - I didn't think about Gradle specification:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs/youtube', include: '*.jar')
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs/youtube/libs', include: '*.jar')
```

Comment: I now however have a different issue, where classes referenced by the internal YouTube API and library are not being found :\

Comment: ANSWER to my comment about the video not playing: Only provide the YouTube ID and not the entire YouTube URL to the loadVideo() function.