# add Youtube Data API in Android Studio using Gradle

Tags: java, android, youtube, android-gradle-plugin

Android Studio cannot find the necessary YouTube classes in my application. I'm recycling some code of a previous project. In the previous project I just imported the jar file provided by google. But I want to learn a better way using gradle. I've used gradle before with success. Its awesome when it works. I've been able to add dependencies using gradle before. But for some reason I can't get a google lib to download or activate or whatever it needs to do so that my IDE can find all these missing youtube symbols. I've done the usual syncing with gradle and rebuilding and cleaning and all that but it hasn't helped.

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dayspringwesleyan.org.dayspringwesleyanchurch"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev141-1.20.0'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.6'
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at this [link](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7048)

Comment: Thank's Partha. This is kind of sad :(

Comment: compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev141-1.20.0'  not resolve error like Error:(15, 41) error: package com.google.android.youtube.player does not exist

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add YouTube Data API to Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175397/add-youtube-data-api-to-android-studio)