# Youtube API in my Android app

Tags: android, youtube-data-api

I am working on an app which should have a YouTube player in it, I tried integrating YouTube API in my app as explained in the link below

[Youtube API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175397/add-youtube-data-api-to-android-studio/40419537#40419537)

But now I am at a roadblock wherein I am getting the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'android'" for the import statements i am using.

Here is my code

```
package com.nobull.jkrishnan.youtubeapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }
}
```

And here is my app gradle file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 25
   buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.nobull.jkrishnan.youtubeapp"
       minSdkVersion 10
       targetSdkVersion 25
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
       testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
       exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
   })
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile files('libs/YoutubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar');
```

compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev178-1.22.0'
    }

I added the line compile `'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev178-1.22.0'`

and the error went away but now there is a compilation error,

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies'.
> Dependency Error. See console for details.
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Answer (score -1):

You can't use youtube as dependency, You need to place youtube.jar to your lib folder in your project.

Comment: All of these are able to be used by Gradle http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.google.apis%22%20AND%20a%3A%22google-api-services-youtube%22