# Unable to resolve YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi dependency

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have created a project and try'n adding YouTubeAndroidPlayer jar [dependency](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/) but couldn' able to resolve it.
The gradle is able to sync it but while Inherting and using it, it might not able to resolve and throwing compile time error. I am using 2.3.2 version of Android studio. Please check the attached .gradle and .java file screenshot.

[image: gradle file heirarchy]

and Java file :

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just got it worked luckily, steps:
- Firstly, Added a New Module of type Jar file, it puts an entry like this under libs folder:

[image]

- Secondly, Under app directory -> inside libs folder -> need to copy same JAR file.

[image]

This resolves the issue. Since I am a newbie in android, does make it resolve somehow.

Thanks.

Comment: I got late I guess, I didn't check this answer and worked on your code. Nevertheless, you got your solution. It's good.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code, it was missing Jar file. Just copy the "YoutubeAPI" jar from their developer's website and paste it into your "libs" folder. Sync your project and it will work!

**Other Solution:**

Remove that last Youtube Jar import line and delete the jar file from your "libs" folder as well. Simply add this line in your dependencies block to import directly from dependency support site:

```
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev181-1.22.0'
```

It will automatically resolve all issues. For details check this link:

[Add YouTube Data API to Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175397/add-youtube-data-api-to-android-studio)

Comment: Hi Zohaib, It exists in libs folder since I copied/imported and add it correctly.

Comment: You Jar files are already being included in first line of "dependencies" block, remove the last line where yo are trying to add the Jar file again.Maybe it's conflicting with each other.Then sync and clean the project.

Comment: tried, but didn't get to work. Again pressing Alt + Enter on import package didn't work.

Comment: tried this practice too: "compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev181-1.22.0'" but couldn't get it to work. Could you please look into the sample(https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiZPHoUDt5_ClA8eV573_A2-CbLt) and suggest.

Comment: Yeah sure.I'll look into it in the night and will get back to you.

Comment: I checked your sample, it was missing the "Jar" file in your "libs" folder. I have copied Jar and it's working fine. Download this updated code and import it. Hope it will work.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/luzgcikzix1rlt9/MoviePortal2.rar?dl=0